# Javascript - get data available outside an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I have a fetch function inside a async function. I would like to be able to call my data variable outside the async() function. I can do that when using only fetch function but it continues to the next lines of code without waiting to finish fetching data. This question [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) doesn't solve my problem. It's using ajax. I am expecting having the response outside the function vs inside.

```
const request = async () => {
  current_url = window.location.href
  network_id = parseInt(current_url.split('/')[5]) 
  const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/network/${network_id}/edges.geojson/`);
  const data = await response.json();
 }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `return await response.json()`?

Comment: @FelixKling, I don't understand. Ialready have await response inside the function

Comment: If you want to get the data "out" of the function you have to return it from that function.

Comment: `return response.json()` will work as well. To get the value: `request().then(data => { ... })` or await it: `const data = await request()`

Comment: with var data =  await response.json(); I tried return data but when I console.log(data) outside the function I got an error data is undefined

Comment: @aba2s You can't access data like that - `data` is only available inside the function. However, if you return `data` from the function, you can get its value using any of the options shown in the one of the [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100385/javascript-get-data-available-outside-an-async-function#comment122128370_69100385)

Comment: @Yousaf, the first method is working fine but the second (const data = await request()) is throwing an error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. Lots of thanks !

Comment: @aba2s error message is pretty descriptive - `const data = await reques()` needs to be inside an `async` function. If you don't want to do that, just use the `then()` method